# Data Base Design for Laravel-Lumen API

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, database-design

I need help with Database design and tables relationships for my upcoming project with Laravel-Lumen to reduce the query time as much as possible, Below I will describe all of my tables and API endpoints (I will list only the necessary filed from each table)

```
Table - Customer
-id
-name
-image
.
.


Table - Item
-id
-customer_id
-name
-price
-image
.
.
+ 8 more


Table Item_color

-id
-item_id
-red
-black
.
.

Table Favorites

-id
-user_id
-item_id
```

My endpoints is :

- getItems (list all items)
- getUseFavorites (list user Favorites items)

Note :  I didn't use eloquent relationships.

```
SELECT * from item, customer.name, customer.img_url,customer.location,item_color.red,item_color.blue,item_color.white
JOIN customer ON item.id = customer.id
JOIN sidedish ON item.id = item_color.item_id
WHERE item.location = $location
```

For the first endpoint I have to retrieve all items fields + customer name, image and location + all item colors (for this query I use JION)

For the second endpoint I have to retrieve all Favorites items of the user which I use JOIN as well.

My issue after running factories with over 500 users and items and 50 Favorites item per user is the queries time took 3.8 sec to accomplish the above endpoints, so now i'm thinking what if the App hit 10000 users or more? after search i found to many articles states that using unoptimized JION query will slow down you app, So any suggestions, ideas will be much appreciated

Comment: Make sure you have proper indexes. Page your items so that the consumer decides how many pages of items they want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries are very slow when there is no index on your database, all primary keys and foreign keys should be indexed, you can define it's on you migrations (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#indexes).

As mencioned by @adam, paginate your results (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination#paginating-eloquent-results).

Third advice is return only needed fields, so use `select('name', 'image')` to get only what you need (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#selects).

Use model relationships, it will not improve you query time, but will your development time.

If you are using MySQL or MariaDB, you can print sql statement with method `toSql()` (https://scotch.io/tutorials/debugging-queries-in-laravel) and use `EXPLAIN` statement to try to identify what is happening (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html).